# Sampling from a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 112k rows and 2 columns.   How do I sample equaly from this dataset to obtain a small data set of like 10k rows?

I mean equaly because this dataset has 56k rows with a column name `True=1` and 56k  rows with column ``´True=0```.

So i want to sample 10k row with 5k  with column  `True=1` and 5k with `True=0`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a small sample, did you try using pandas `sample`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a stratified random sample with equal allocation (i.e. the sample from each group is the same size) which happens in this case also to be *proportional* allocation (the sample from each group is proportional to the size of the group).

It can be achieved using  [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html):

```
df.groupby("my_column").sample(n=5000)
```

There are a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026935/sample-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-in-proportion-to-counts-in-a-column) [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114463/stratified-sampling-in-pandas) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035187/stratified-samples-from-pandas) on this topic but they relate to slightly more complicated cases and seem to have been answered before the `groupby.sample` method was introduced in pandas v1.1.

Answer (score 3):

[For dataset split StratifiedKFold would help](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)

```
This cross-validation object is a variation of KFold that returns stratified folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.
```

USAGE

```py
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)
>>> skf.get_n_splits(X, y)
2
>>> print(skf)  
StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
>>> for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [1 3] TEST: [0 2]
TRAIN: [0 2] TEST: [1 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
step_size = 5
a[0::step_size]
```

Output: [1, 6, 11, 16]

```
sample_count = 5
a[0::int(len(a)/sample_count)]
```

Output: [1, 5, 9, 13, 17]