# How can I select rows randomly in proportion to the number of unique values for each group in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to random select rows proportionate to the number of unique values in column "ID" grouping by column "Team". Further, I would like to only retrieve 8 total rows. I have:

```
|  ID   |  Team |  Color       |
| ----- | ----- | ------------ |
|  1    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  2    |  B    |  Red         |
|  2    |  B    |  Green       |
|  3    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  6    |  C    |  Red         |
|  1    |  B    |  Yellow      |
|  2    |  B    |  Green       |
|  9    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  6    |  C    |  Red         |
|  1    |  B    |  Yellow      |
|  9    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  1    |  A    |  Purple      |
```

Only the proportions are looking at unique values. The rows pulled do not necessarily need to be unique in anyway. Using the above table the proportions would be:

```
|  Team  | Unique IDs |  Proportion |  Number selected |
| ------ | ---------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
|  A     |    3       |  0.500      |       4          |
|  B     |    2       |  0.333      |       3          |
|  C     |    1       |  0.167      |       1          |
```

So since I want 8 total rows selected proportionately, I should end up with something like the following:

```
|  ID   |  Team |  Color       |
| ----- | ----- | ------------ |
|  1    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  3    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  9    |  A    |  Blue        |
|  1    |  A    |  Purple      |
|  2    |  B    |  Green       |
|  2    |  B    |  Red         |
|  1    |  B    |  Yellow      |
|  6    |  C    |  Red         |
```

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46026935/14627505) is related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Calculate **unique_counts** - the number of unique `'ID'`s in each `'Team'` group,
- convert **unique_counts** into **nums_selected** - the number of elements for each group that have to be selected
- use **nums_selected** to [`.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) this many elements from each `'Team'` group:

```py
n_total = 8
unique_counts = df.groupby('Team')['ID'].agg('nunique')
nums_selected= np.floor(unique_counts / unique_counts.sum() * n_total).astype(int)  # rounded down

df.groupby('Team', group_keys=False).apply(      # for each 'Team' group:
    lambda x: x.sample(n=nums_selected[x.name],  # sample this many rows
                       replace=True)             # (with replacement)
    )
```

> Note:
>
> The result can contain less elements than **n_total** because **nums_selected** are rounded down when converting from `float` to `int`. However, you may use any method to do this conversion: [`np.ceil`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html), [`pd.Series.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html), or any other method you choose to your liking.

Comment: That works wonderfully. May I ask how the "randomness" of selection is performed? Is it generating a random index value for that group and pulling it or by some other means?

Comment: @brandooo23 [`.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) selects random rows. By the way, if you want reproducibility (same random selection every time) "you can use random_state"